# The transparent background imageview makes the normally opaque text that comes on it also transparent. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, imageview, transparency

What I want is a fully opaque text on a transparent background imageview. Without the image the webview text is opaque and text that isnt on the the background imageview is still opaque. Only the parts of the text that comes on the transparent image becomes transparent as seen on the screenshot i provided. Its quite interesting and altough I have searched, I couldnt find a solution for this.

Here is the current screenshot:

[image]

here is my xml layout

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

<WebView
android:id="@+id/tvAnimalJoke"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text=""
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

 />
```

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivAwesome"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/awesome50jp"
/>
```

and here is my webview in java

```
Random r = new Random();
number = r.nextInt(9851);
String randomjoke = getStreamTextByLine("9851.txt", number);
String numstr = Integer.toString(number);
String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file:///android_asset/annoyingkettle.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';}</style></head>";
String htmlData = "<html>" + head + numstr + "<body>" + "<p    align=\"justify\">"
        + randomjoke + "</p>" + "</body></html>";

Mywebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8",
        "about:blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip the ImageView and the Webview in your layout.  FrameLayouts add their children bottom up so your ImageView is actually on top of the WebView containing the text, not underneath it.

Another note is that a ScrollView should only have one child.  You should wrap your WebView and ImageView in a FrameLayout.  But, you shouldn't really need to put a WebView in a ScrollView so you should really just make everything match parent and let the WebView handle the scrolling of the text.  Make sure to test this on different API levels because the behavior of WebView's background (in regards to opacity) is different on different API levels.